# Split Cell by " - "

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have this kind of cell

```
David - England - 08-01-2016
Fred - England - 07-03-2017
Nova - AS - 25-11-2016
```

And I want to split cell by the dash and space `(" - ")` only, so the date or may other words with dash without space `("-")` not split.

```
David  England  08-01-2016
Fred   England  07-03-2017
Nova   AS       25-11-2016
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! So that said, what have you done to attempt to solve this issue? As it stands you are not providing any code so this reads as a coding/scripting request and this site is not about requesting free code/scripts.

Comment: I attempt to split the cell with ("-") delimited, but it will split all data by ("-") even the date.

Comment: You could do a search and replace to replace all " - " with some single character that doesn't appear in the content.  Then split based on that character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with Power Query, a free Microsoft add-in for Excel 2010 and 2013 and built into Excel 2016 / 365 as Get and Transform.

Split column by delimiter, set a custom delimiter " - " (space dash space) as the delimiter.

The date will remain unaffected, because the delimiter is not space dash space.